# Add number of rows in Table Javascript

Tags: javascript, pagination

There are number of plugins of Javascript that can export table data. Take the example of [this](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html). Can I add dropdown value to select number of rows in every page? In default setting there are 10 rows/page. I want to increase this to 20. I tried several options but couldn't make it.

Something has to be added on this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#example').DataTable( {
           dom: 'Bfrtip',
           buttons: [
               'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
           ]
       } );
   } );
```

Comment: pageLength

Change the initial page length (number of rows per page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuation to Rio answer.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('#example').DataTable( {
           dom: 'Bfrtip',
           "pageLength": 50,
           buttons: [
               'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'pageLength'
           ]
       } );
   } );
```

Answer (score 1):

The example in documentation is here
https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "pageLength": 50
} );
```

Comment: how can we have dropdown, is there any builtin function for that ?